# Provide another model's fields for nested form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

I have a Rails app I'm building to manage a fantasy tennis bracket game.

Here are my models.

The game where the players will submit their picks:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :picks, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :picks
```

The matches where I match up two tennis players:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :player_1, class_name: "Player"
  belongs_to :player_2, class_name: "Player"
  has_many :picks, dependent: :destroy
```

The pick model.

```
class Pick < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :match
```

I am using a nested form inside of another form which I have working.

```
<%= form_for(@game) do |f| %>
  <% if @game.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@game.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this game from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @game.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :event_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:event_id, Event.all, :id, :title) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :score %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :score %>
  </div>
  <% @matches.each do |g| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :picks do |ff| %>
        <fieldset>
          <%= ff.label :match_id %>
          <%= ff.text_field :match_id %>
          <%= ff.label :winner, "Select the Winner" %> 
          <%= ff.text_field :winner %>
        </fieldset>
        <br>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>   
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I would like to use the fields from the Match model to populate the fields on the Pick model. For example, the Match has two players, I want to be able to pull the player's names into the :picks form, and will probably use an f.select on them.

I have some player data on the Match model I want to dynamically pull into the Pick model. Can't figure out how to query the database and get the field attributes to be accessed by the Pick nested form. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd do.

1. Get rid of "games"
2. Make "picks" the model to store "game" information

I think the major issue you have currently is the `Game` and `Pick` models are trying to do the same thing.

```
#app/models/match.rb
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    # columns id | event_id | name | player_1 | player_2
    belongs_to :event
    has_many :picks
    belongs_to :player_1, class_name: "Player", primary_key: :player_1
    belongs_to :player_2, class_name: "Player", primary_key: :player_2

    def players
       [player_1, player_2]
    end
end

#app/models/pick.rb
class Pick < ActiveRecord::Base
    # columns id | user_id | match | winner | etc
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :match, primary_key: :match
    has_one :winner, primary_key: :winner
end
```

This means you'll be able to do the following:

```
#app/views/picks/new.html.erb
<% @matches.each do |match| %>
    <%= match.name %>
    <%= form_for match.picks.new do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :match, match.id %>
        <%= f.collection_select :winner, match.players, :id, :name, prompt: "Who will win?" %>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/picks_controller.rb
class PicksController < ActionController::Base
   def new
       @matches = Match.all
   end
   def create
       @pick = Pick.new pick_params
       @pick.save
   end

   private

   def pick_params
       params.require(:pick).permit(:match, :winner).merge(user_id: current_user)
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to "pick" the players in the most simple & extensible way.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I followed your advice in a sandbox (a new rails app) and I'm getting an error: undefined method 'pick'. I've tried to add an @ to match, and substitute in matches. Any other thoughts? I think this is on the right track and your post has already been very helpful.

Comment: Where's the error appearing, does it give you a file and line reference?

Comment: It does give a file: app/views/picks/_form.html.erb:3:in `block in _app_views_picks__form_html_erb__3689731985020291361_70286657363160'

Comment: Reference link is 433. Here is 431 - 436:       else
        match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
        match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
      end
    end

Comment: Also the top error is: NoMethodError in PicksController#new

Comment: Can you screenshot? I think I might know the issue, but I need to clarify. It might be something to do with `match.pick.new` or something in the `new` action.

Comment: Hmm okay it looks like `match.pick.new` is the problem. Can you change it to `match.picks.new` by any chance? I think I messed up the association name :)

Comment: Ding, ding, ding. We have a winner! Thank you, Rich!